# Merge multiple xarray Datasets with overlapping coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm trying to merge multiple Datasets having overlapping coordinates into one. When I set `compat=` to `'override'`, only the values of the first Dataset are kept and the rest of the resulting Dataset is set to nan. I'm fine using any of the intersecting values for cells with conflicts.

See the example below

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr


temperature = np.random.randint(1,255,size=(9,10,10))
precipitation = np.random.randint(1,255,size=(9,10,10))
lon = np.linspace(10,100,10)
lat = np.linspace(10,100,10)
time_0 = pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=9, freq='2D')
time_1 = pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=9, freq='3D')

ds_0 = xr.Dataset(
       data_vars=dict(
           temperature=(('time', 'y', 'x'), temperature),
           precipitation=(('time', 'y', 'x'), precipitation)),
       coords=dict(
           x=lon,
           y=lat,
           time=time_0)
)
ds_1 = xr.Dataset(
       data_vars=dict(
           temperature=(('time', 'y', 'x'), temperature),
           precipitation=(('time', 'y', 'x'), precipitation)),
       coords=dict(
           x=lon + 90,
           y=lat,
           time=time_0)
)
ds_2 = xr.Dataset(
       data_vars=dict(
           temperature=(('time', 'y', 'x'), temperature),
           precipitation=(('time', 'y', 'x'), precipitation)),
       coords=dict(
           x=lon + 90,
           y=lat + 90,
           time=time_1)
)
ds_3 = xr.Dataset(
       data_vars=dict(
           temperature=(('time', 'y', 'x'), temperature),
           precipitation=(('time', 'y', 'x'), precipitation)),
       coords=dict(
           x=lon,
           y=lat + 90,
           time=time_1)
)

# Combine
ds = xr.merge([ds_0, ds_1, ds_2, ds_3], compat='override')
print(ds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep - the intended & documented behavior of `xr.merge` when `compat='override'` is to use the first passed data object's coordinates. From the [xr.merge docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.merge.html):

> **compat** (`{"identical", "equals", "broadcast_equals", "no_conflicts", "override"}`, *optional*) – String indicating how to compare variables of the same name for potential conflicts:
>
> - “broadcast_equals”: all values must be equal when variables are broadcast against each other to ensure common dimensions.
> - “equals”: all values and dimensions must be the same.
> - “identical”: all values, dimensions and attributes must be the same.
> - “no_conflicts”: only values which are not null in both datasets must be equal. The returned dataset then contains the combination of all non-null values.
> - “override”: skip comparing and pick variable from first dataset

So I think you're probably looking for `compat='no_conflicts'`.